# How to select the last value of a child tag, if exists, from a repeating parent tag?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML which has multiple stacks for a worker. Each effective stack will include some child tags, but the child tags are not consistent. Some of them may be same, or they can completely differ as well. I want to select the value of a child tag that might repeat in the multiple stacks, but only the value that occurs in the last stack where it exists.

I have idea about the position() function but not sure how it can be used dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:weci="urn:com.workday/weci">
<weci:Summary>
    <weci:Integration_Event>72a8f2c9af8701b8a3faa214ea017003</weci:Integration_Event>
    <weci:Integration_Sent_On>2019-07-12T02:01:49.363-07:00</weci:Integration_Sent_On>
    <weci:Restricted_to_Organizations/>
    <weci:Updated_From>2019-06-09T14:00:00.000-07:00</weci:Updated_From>
    <weci:Updated_To>2019-07-02T04:00:32.890-07:00</weci:Updated_To>
    <weci:Effective_From>2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Effective_From>
    <weci:Effective_To>2019-08-02-07:00</weci:Effective_To>
    <weci:Future_Effective_Moment_To/>
    <weci:Primary_Run>false</weci:Primary_Run>
    <weci:Ad_Hoc_Run>true</weci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
    <weci:Full_Snapshot>false</weci:Full_Snapshot>
    <weci:Change_Detection>Include all changes in the effective date
        range</weci:Change_Detection>
    <weci:Future_Change_Detection>false</weci:Future_Change_Detection>
    <weci:Worker_Type_for_Integrartion_Run>employees and
        Contingents</weci:Worker_Type_for_Integrartion_Run>
    <weci:Worker_Count>1</weci:Worker_Count>
    <weci:Version>1</weci:Version>
</weci:Summary>
<weci:Worker>
    <weci:Worker_Summary>
        <weci:WID>97b2eaa66880011f3ed47f611c131ea3</weci:WID>
        <weci:Employee_ID>10000158</weci:Employee_ID>
        <weci:Name>Kaisa Kassa</weci:Name>
    </weci:Worker_Summary>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="0">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-14T01:56:37.707-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Worker_Status weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:Status weci:isAdded="1">Active</weci:Status>
            <weci:Worker_Reference_Type>EE</weci:Worker_Reference_Type>
            <weci:Active weci:priorValue="0">1</weci:Active>
            <weci:Active_Status_Date weci:isAdded="1">2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Active_Status_Date>
            <weci:Terminated>0</weci:Terminated>
            <weci:Hire_Date weci:isAdded="1">2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Hire_Date>
            <weci:Original_Hire_Date weci:isAdded="1">2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Original_Hire_Date>
            <weci:Hire_Rescinded>0</weci:Hire_Rescinded>
            <weci:Hire_Reason weci:isAdded="1"
                >Hire_Employee_Hire_Employee_New_Position</weci:Hire_Reason>
            <weci:Is_Rehire>0</weci:Is_Rehire>
            <weci:Continuous_Service_Date weci:isAdded="1"
                >2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Continuous_Service_Date>
            <weci:First_Day_of_Work weci:isAdded="1">2019-06-01-07:00</weci:First_Day_of_Work>
            <weci:Seniority_Date weci:isAdded="1">2019-06-01-07:00</weci:Seniority_Date>
            <weci:Regrettable_Termination>0</weci:Regrettable_Termination>
            <weci:Not_Returning>0</weci:Not_Returning>
            <weci:Return_Unknown>0</weci:Return_Unknown>
        </weci:Worker_Status>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="1">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-14T00:00:00.000-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-14T02:10:30.480-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Person_Communication weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:Address weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:Address_Line_1>XYZ</weci:Address_Line_1>
                <weci:Postal_Code>00100</weci:Postal_Code>
                <weci:Country>FI</weci:Country>
            </weci:Address>
        </weci:Person_Communication>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="2">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-14T01:56:37.707-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-14T01:56:37.707-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Personal weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:Legal_Name>
                <weci:Country>FI</weci:Country>
                <weci:First_Name>Kaisa</weci:First_Name>
                <weci:Last_Name>Kassa</weci:Last_Name>
                <weci:General_Display_Name>Kaisa Kassa</weci:General_Display_Name>
            </weci:Legal_Name>
            <weci:Citizenship>
                <weci:Citizenship_Status_ID>FIN_Citizen</weci:Citizenship_Status_ID>
            </weci:Citizenship>
            <weci:Gender>Female</weci:Gender>
            <weci:Date_of_Birth>2xxx-xx-xx-08:00</weci:Date_of_Birth>
            <weci:Preferred_Language>en_US</weci:Preferred_Language>
            <weci:Preferred_Locale>fi_FI</weci:Preferred_Locale>
            <weci:Workday_Account weci:isAdded="1">kkassa</weci:Workday_Account>
        </weci:Personal>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="3">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-14T02:19:32.025-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-14T02:19:32.025-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Person_Identification weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:National_Identifier weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:National_ID>01xxx-0101</weci:National_ID>
                <weci:National_ID_Type>FIN-KELA</weci:National_ID_Type>
                <weci:Country>FI</weci:Country>
                <weci:Verification_Date>2019-06-19-07:00</weci:Verification_Date>
            </weci:National_Identifier>
            <weci:License weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:License_ID>xx</weci:License_ID>
                <weci:License_ID_Type>Alcohol_License</weci:License_ID_Type>
                <weci:Verification_Date>2019-06-14-07:00</weci:Verification_Date>
                <weci:Verified_By>08135028</weci:Verified_By>
            </weci:License>
        </weci:Person_Identification>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="4">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-19T03:31:37.196-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-19T03:31:37.196-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Person_Identification weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:National_Identifier weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:National_ID>02xxx-01x1</weci:National_ID>
                <weci:National_ID_Type>FIN-KELA</weci:National_ID_Type>
                <weci:Country>FI</weci:Country>
                <weci:Verification_Date>2019-06-19-07:00</weci:Verification_Date>
            </weci:National_Identifier>
            <weci:License>
                <weci:License_ID>xx</weci:License_ID>
                <weci:License_ID_Type>Alcohol_License</weci:License_ID_Type>
                <weci:Verification_Date>2019-06-14-07:00</weci:Verification_Date>
                <weci:Verified_By>08135028</weci:Verified_By>
            </weci:License>
        </weci:Person_Identification>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="5">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-06-19T03:46:48.634-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-06-19T03:46:48.634-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Person_Communication weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:Address>
                <weci:Address_Line_1>Kotitie 1</weci:Address_Line_1>
                <weci:Postal_Code>00100</weci:Postal_Code>
                <weci:Country>FI</weci:Country>
            </weci:Address>
            <weci:Phone weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:Area_Code>9</weci:Area_Code>
                <weci:Phone_Number>123456</weci:Phone_Number>
            </weci:Phone>
            <weci:Email weci:isAdded="1">
                <weci:Usage_Type>HOME</weci:Usage_Type>
                <weci:Email_Address>test@test.com</weci:Email_Address>
            </weci:Email>
        </weci:Person_Communication>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
    <weci:Effective_Change weci:Sequence="6">
        <weci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</weci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <weci:Effective_Moment>2019-08-01T00:00:00.000-07:00</weci:Effective_Moment>
        <weci:Entry_Moment>2019-07-02T03:53:10.426-07:00</weci:Entry_Moment>
        <weci:Position weci:isUpdated="1">
            <weci:Position_ID>P50573627</weci:Position_ID>
            <weci:Primary_Job>1</weci:Primary_Job>
            <weci:Business_Title>Salesperson supermarket trade (commerce
                salesperson)</weci:Business_Title>
            <weci:Worker_Type>Permanent</weci:Worker_Type>
            <weci:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</weci:Position_Time_Type>
        </weci:Position>
    </weci:Effective_Change>
</weci:Worker>
```

So, in the above example there are 6 effective sequences and I want to extract the national identifier tag value, which is present in sequence 3 and 4. But the only value I want is from sequence 4 which is the latest value, not the one present in 3. The resulting output file can be an XML

Comment: Check this: `not(preceding::element_name)`

Comment: Well you can select `(//weci:National_Identifier)[last()]`, for example. So using a predicate `[last()]` on the right left hand expression, usually one put into parenthesis, seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you Martin. It worked. :) My mistake was that I was traversing the effective stack in a for loop and was using the last() function inside it instead of straight away using it outside.